# SBJSON ios 5 or native apple JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

Just started using JSON in iOS. I have a previous version of an application that uses SBJSON. I am rebuilding it from the ground up, and was wondering if I should continue to use SBJSON or apple's native JSON support?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the builtin class? `NSJSONSerialization` works just fine, and you'll have one less dependency.

Comment: ok, just checking, making sure that it isn't a disadvantage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people have done some research on this and seems like NSJSONSerialization is more performant than SBJSON

http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance

Comment: Not able to open this link. can you please tell me which is best in performance?

Comment: The blog suggested that for typical use-cases, NSJSONSerialization is more performant than SBJSON

Comment: which one is best option for iOS > 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I see for staying with the SBJSON classes is iOS < 5.0 compatibility. If you plan on targeting iOS 5.0 and up, I'd go with the native `NSJSONSerialization`. Native is almost always the better option when developing for iOS, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Note that SBJSON (and my modified version of KSJSON) supports custom object serialization, which not only makes it – of course – slower than NSJSONSerialization, but also might be exactly what you need.

NSJSONSerialization does not support object graphs with custom classes.